# Python sort data frame based on argsort result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame `df`, where I would like to sort the values in each row based on the indices I get from the `argsort` function. I get the indices as follows:

```
idx = np.argsort(df, axis=1)
```

Now I would like to use the result `idx` to sort all rows of `df`, as well as all rows of a different data frame (let's call it `df2`) with the same shape. I am however unable to achieve this. My attempt to sort it using `df[idx]` didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does `df.iloc[idx]` or `df.loc[idx]` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I want. It's probably not the cleanest solution but it does the trick:

```
idx = np.argsort(df, axis=1)
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(data=np.take_along_axis(df.to_numpy(), idx.to_numpy(), axis=1), columns=df.columns)
```